# Add output with condition to a stored procedure in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

When I execute the procedure I fill in the ID of the reserve part (mechanic shop), number of parts, and casenumber.

I'm trying to add an output somewhere which triggers if the number of parts I select are >= to the number of parts in stock, and outputs a message "reorder part"

The script works, it just doesn't do everything I need it to, yet.

```
resid = reserve part id
antal = number of parts
sagsnummer = case number
Reservedele = spare parts


CREATE PROCEDURE sp_opret_forbrug
    @resid      int, 
    @antal      int,
    @sagsnummer int
AS 
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO dbo.forbrug (resid, antal, sagsnummer)
    VALUES (@resid, @antal, @sagsnummer) 

    UPDATE [dbo].[Reservedele]
    SET antal = Reservedele.antal - @antal
    WHERE reservedele.resid = @resid;
END 

--exec sp_opret_forbrug

--@resid = '49',

--@antal = '2',

--@sagsnummer ='11'

--drop procedure sp_opret_forbrug
```

[image: Picture of the tables]

Comment: Side note (for SQL Server): you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: 1) How do you want to return the message? (there are multiple mechanisms to do so). 2) Please demonstrate with sample data how you would detect the stock level, and the query you would use to detect it.

Comment: You can use `IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM Reservedele WHERE antal < @antal ) PRINT 'reorder part'`. `PRINT` will print a message to "console", this message can also be captured by other programs. Alternatively, instead of `PRINT 'message'` you can use `SELECT 'reorder part' AS message` or add an output variable. For more info and examples see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Alex, thanks a lot, your solution worked, I can still beautify it a little bit by making sure parts cant be a negative value and stop the procedure from executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could throw an error using `THROW`

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE sp_opret_forbrug
    @resid      int, 
    @antal      int,
    @sagsnummer int
AS 

SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM [dbo].[Reservedele]
    WHERE reservedele.resid = @resid
      AND Reservedele.antal < @antal)
  THROW 50000, 'Not enough stock, reorder', 0;

INSERT INTO dbo.forbrug (resid, antal, sagsnummer)
    VALUES (@resid, @antal, @sagsnummer) 

UPDATE [dbo].[Reservedele]
    SET antal = Reservedele.antal - @antal
    WHERE reservedele.resid = @resid;

COMMIT;
```